# Why can't you reference method definitions from a static context?

Tags: c#, wpf

Cannot access the non static method AddNew from static context.

Referenced classes:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute);
    public RelayCommand(Action execute);
    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute);
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute);
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter);
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}

  [TypeForwardedFrom("PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")]
  [TypeConverter("System.Windows.Input.CommandConverter, PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, Custom=null")]
  [ValueSerializer("System.Windows.Input.CommandValueSerializer, PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, Custom=null")]
  public interface ICommand
  {
    /// <summary>Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.</summary>
    /// <returns>true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.</returns>
    /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    bool CanExecute(object parameter);
    /// <summary>Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.</summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    void Execute(object parameter);
    /// <summary>Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.</summary>
    event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
  }
```

My Code:

```
public class ExampleViewModel: NotificationObject
{

    public ICommand AddNewCommand { get; } = new Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand(AddNew, CanAdd); // method references arn't static??

    public String NewName { get; set; } = "";

    internal bool CanAdd()
    {
        //Can Add if string is non empty & non null
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewName);
    }

    internal void AddNew()
    {
        var name = NewName ?? "NeedToCheckforNull";

        var newWindSpeedEnv = new WindSpeedEnvelope()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = name
        };
    }
}
```

Coming from Java, I would have expected this to work, as the methods are known to exist statically at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initialize the DelegateCommand in the ExampleViewModel constructor:

```
public ExampleViewModel()
{
    AddNewCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddNew, CanAdd);
}

public ICommand AddNewCommand { get; private set; }
```

As a side note, `NewName` will never evaluate to null as you're giving it a value of `string.Empty`, so the  null coalescing operator isn't doing anything there.

Comment: Cheers for the side note, the code in this section is still very much in flux as I copy from older classes around the place trying to learn and clean stuff up.

I understand that if I populate it inside the constructor instead of as a auto-property initializer that it should work right?

Comment: Should do, I would verify it myself but Prism's download size is terrifying :-)

Comment: I've edited the answer to contain the minimal definitions of the classes I referenced.

Comment: The duplicate flagged by Martin should give you a better explanation than I have.